# Drag and drop isn't working in Virtualbox, despite being enabled

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running a Linux Mint guest OS inside a Linux Mint host OS in Virtualbox, and I've noticed that dragging an icon from the guest OS desktop onto the host OS desktop simply pushes the icon to the edge of the desktop, instead of dropping it onto the other desktop. On one occasion (by sheer luck), I successfully dropped a file from a Linux Mint guest onto a Linux Mint host desktop, but on all other other occasions, it didn't work (and I got the same error message.) I have installed guest additions, and I'm also accessing the .vdi image from a separate hard disk partition (the .vdi is on a separate Windows partition, on the same computer.) What are some possible reasons for this problem?

Comment: What version of virtualbox are you using?

Comment: @Jay I'm using Virtualbox version 4.2.0 r80737 (on Windows). Are there any known issues with drag-and-drop for this version of Virtualbox, or  is drag-and-drop simply unsupported by the guest operating system (Linux Mint)?

Comment: I found that someone else had the same problem that I did (although the reason for this bug is still unclear): https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=52172

Comment: I keep seeing an error message that reads "Error while copying" in the guest OS, and a window appears with the words "Dropping data 99%" in the host OS, but it get stuck at 99% for some reason.

Comment: In my case (on Ubuntu 12.04 on a Windows 7 host): Files with spaces in their names cannot be dragged and dropped for some reason. Files that do NOT have spaces can be dragged and dropped.

Comment: I'm not sure, but the 4.2 version is the first to have the drag and drop feature. According to their website, it is still in the experimental stage and only works on Linux hosts.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using VirtualBox with KxStudio (which uses Ubuntu). It gets stuck at 99% here too. But if you click on the x to close the window, and then go to Home> Documents > VirtualBox Dropped Files, you find it there in a subfolder.

You can then copy it to its desired destination on the guest. So still useful as a way to get files to the guest from the host OS. Might be a useful tip for others in same situation?